# Structure not storing values and scanf failing

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm trying to run the following code with some input, and when the program ends it shows that `scanf` failed and my structure didn't save anything except zeros. What's wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INF 2147483647;

typedef struct info{
    int u, v, w;
    struct info *next;
}*Vertex;

Vertex vertex;
int n, c, sede; 
int *distarr;

int main(){
    int i;

    if(scanf("%d %d\n%d", &n, &c, &sede) < 0)
        printf("first scanf failed\n");

    distarr = malloc(sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
    vertex = malloc(sizeof(struct info));

    for(i=0; i<c; i++){

        if(scanf("%d %d %d", &vertex->u, &vertex->v, &vertex->w) < 0)
            printf("second scanf failed\n");

        vertex->next = malloc(sizeof(struct info));
        vertex = vertex->next;

        printf("u: %d v: %d w: %d\n", vertex->u, vertex->v, vertex->w);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
10 15
6
6 2 5
6 7 -1
8 5 0
8 3 2
5 10 0
10 3 0
3 4 4
3 8 -1
2 5 4
2 10 5
2 3 1
2 9 3
1 6 -1
1 8 0
1 10 3
```

Output:

```
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
u: 0 v: 0 w: 0
```

EDIT: I saw that my condition of scanf was wrong I've changed it, but i still don't understand what is happening to just store 0 (The Code and Output were edited)

Comment: `if(scanf("%d %d\n%d", &n, &c, &sede) != 1)`  -> `if(scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &c, &sede) != 3)`?

Comment: Read more about [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and especially about what it returns.

Comment: @chux I edited the question, maybe I should put again the errors, sorry for that. The part of scanf returning errors I already know. My problem is that it only stores 0, as you can see in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mis-ordered code: Print *then* advance pointer with `vertex = vertex->next;`.

```
    // Add
    printf("u: %d v: %d w: %d\n", vertex->u, vertex->v, vertex->w);

    vertex->next = malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    vertex = vertex->next;
    // printf("u: %d v: %d w: %d\n", vertex->u, vertex->v, vertex->w);
```

Comment: Why does that change my output. I understand that the first line would not be printed, but printing all to 0 i don't get that

Comment: @Miguel Your code was printing `vertex->u` of the newly allocated `vertex` rather than the `vertex` in the preceding `scanf()`.  The printing of `0` happens to be what was in the newly allocated data,  it could have been any `int` - it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d %d\n%d", &n, &c, &sede)` will return `3` on successful scan and of course `3 != 1`. Same goes with `scanf("%d %d %d", &vertex->u, &vertex->v, &vertex->w)`.

Comment: yeah I got that, what about the 0?

Comment: @Miguel; I will answer that but what if you will ask about `-1`, `-2`, `4`, `5`?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. The first three numbers are always positive. The only one that could be negative is w because it is the length of an edge.